# Assert a pandas column type with NaN allowed

Tags: python, pandas, nan, numeric

I'm coding some tests to verify if some columns of a pandas dataframe are integer (or floats for other columns), but with authorized NaN values.

I'm currently trying with assert statements:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.api.types as ptypes

df = pd.read_excel('the_df', na_values='')

try:
    assert(ptypes.is_numeric_dtype(df['a_column']))
except AssertionError:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

But this method returns False when there are NaN and I can't figure out how to fix this. How can I proceed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the dtype, not the entire array:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.api.types as ptypes

df = pd.read_excel('the_df', na_values='')

return ptypes.is_numeric_dtype(df['a_column'].dtype)
```

(You don't need the try-except-else chain: the above achieves the exact same thing: it returns `True` or `False`).

Comment: @Micawber Use `pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df['a_column'].dtype) and (df['a_column'].fillna(0) >= 0).all()`. The evaluation will short circuit, so if the dtype check fails, `.fillna()` isn't even attempted and it's safe for e.g. strings or dates.